# Unresolved external symbol error C++

Tags: external, sfml, symbols

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::SoundStream::play(void)" (__imp_?play@SoundStream@sf@@QAEXXZ)  C:\Users\Nikola\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\LoopsTest1\LoopsTest1\main.obj    LoopsTest1
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall sf::Music::openFromFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_?openFromFile@Music@sf@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)  C:\Users\Nikola\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\LoopsTest1\LoopsTest1\main.obj    LoopsTest1

Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sf::Music::~Music(void)" (__imp_??1Music@sf@@UAE@XZ)    C:\Users\Nikola\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\LoopsTest1\LoopsTest1\main.obj    LoopsTest1
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::Music::Music(void)" (__imp_??0Music@sf@@QAE@XZ) C:\Users\Nikola\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\LoopsTest1\LoopsTest1\main.obj    LoopsTest1
Error   5   error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Nikola\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\LoopsTest1\Release\LoopsTest1.exe LoopsTest1
```

I'm using SFML 2.3 to play an ogg file. I'm a novice to C++. Not sure what's causing it. This is the code I'm using to play the ogg sound.Thanks in advanced. `sf::Music music;
    music.openFromFile("Forest_v3.ogg");
    return -1;
    music.play();`

Edit : I've attempted pasting all the DLLs from SFML/bin into my source files folder but no changes. I've also referenced the sfml-audio-d.lib file but no changes. The errors remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you setup your IDE properly. If using [visual studio](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-vc.php), you need to do the following:

1. Go to your SFML folder >> bin. Then, copy & paste all those DLL's into the same folder as your source files.
2. Then go to Project>>Properties>>Linker>>Input>>Additional Dependencies: and make sure that you have "sfml-audio-d.lib" in there. (While using debug)

**Edit:** Actually, the missing DLL's in the same directory would cause an error dialog box to appear, but not the exception you are having. Are you running in release? Go to Build>>Configuration Manager, and it should say "Debug" under "Active Solution Configuration", as well as under "Configuration".

Update me on your status and I will do the same for my answer.

Comment: Yeah - I was running it in release. Setting it to debug hasn't changed.